# How to prove matrix geometric convergence to any matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, power-series

Suppose I have two vectors $x$ and $v$, and we want to calculate the following expression:
$$(I+x\cdot v^{T})^{-1}$$
My professor affirmed that we could treat this as a "geometric progression"
$$(I-U)^{-1} = I + U + U^2 + U^3 + \ ...$$
but instead, lets replace $U$ by $-U$
$$(I+U)^{-1} = I - U + U^2 - U^3 + \ ...$$
Also, by observing that
$$(x \cdot v^{T})^{2} = x \cdot v^{T} \cdot x \cdot v^{T}$$
but $v^{T} \cdot x$ is a scalar, lets call it $c$. Rearranging...
$$(x \cdot v^{T})^{2} = c \cdot x \cdot v^{T}$$
Therefore, we can conclude
$$(x \cdot v^{T})^{r} = c^{r-1} \cdot x \cdot v^{T}$$

Now, (here is the **1st question**), somehow that expression 
$$(I+U)^{-1} = I - U + U^2 - U^3 + \ ...$$
to infer that
$$(I+x\cdot v^{T})^{-1} = I - (1+c)^{-1} \cdot x\cdot v^T$$

I did a couple of examples and it actually works (of course). Than I dug in, I found on [google](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~math211/m211oh/m211oh96.pdf) that to that convergence happen $U$ must satisfy some conditions, for example, being a [Convergence Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_matrix).

My **2nd question** is: Why this works even though $U$ seems to have no restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work for all $x,v$. The resulting matrix $I-xv^T$ needs to be invertible.

If for instance $x=v= \pmatrix{1\\0\\ \vdots \\ 0 }$, then $I-xv^T$ is not invertible.

On the other hand, if $I-xv^T$ is invertible, then the inverse is given by your formula
$$
(I-xv^T)^{-1} = I + \frac1{1 - x^Tv}x^Tv
$$
since
$$
(I-xv^T)(I + \frac1{1 - x^Tv}xv^T)= I-xv^T + \frac1{1 - x^Tv}xv^T -\frac{x^Tv}{1 - x^Tv}xv^T=I.
$$
You might want to check the [Sherman-Morrison formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula)

Comment: Yes, $I + xv^T$ needs to be invertible. When I meant that U seemed to have no restriction, I accidentally excluded this one.
I didn't understand the way you developed "my formula". I guess that, it suppose to be: 
$$(I+xv^T)^{-1}=I-\frac{1}{1+v^Tx}x^Tv$$
I mean, instead $x^Tv$ it should be $v^Tx$, right?
Also, I just fixed the signal up there. Sorry, I typed $(I - xv^T)^{-1}$ when it suppose to be $(I+xv^T)^{-1}$

Comment: But, yeah, the [Sherman-Morrison formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) is exactly the reference I was looking for. I had hit it before, but just now that you mentioned it I realized that is just use the identity $I$ as the $A$ matrix.